# Linux Camera Driver Communication Enable Pin Setting i.MX6Q Issue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, camera, linux-device-driver

I am writing MIPI csi-2 camera driver on Linux but I have a problem about communication enable signal. I have the technical data sheet in my hand but the communication enables register or another info about how to set or get this signal is not mentioned. I think this signal is getting from device tree I don't know. This signal called datasheet as an XCE signal and these are the information about that;

> 1. XCE: Communication enable 4-wire: XCE pin and I2C: Fixed to High

[image: This is the communication schematic]

> The pin for 4-wire serial communication and I2C communication is shared, so the external pin XCE must be fixed to power supply side when using I2C communication

these are some information about that other information of XCE is about how to use it while configuring the camera.
I need some advice or any idea to figure out how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Best Regards

Comment: First of all, you need to describe how you intend to connect this camera.  What interface are you going to use, I2C or *"4-wire serial"* (which seems to be SPI)?

Comment: @sawdust These camera uses both 4 wire serial and i2c communication . Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: *"These camera uses both 4 wire serial and i2c communication"* -- Highly unlikely.  They may have two interfaces, but you're probably supposed to choose and use only one of them.

Comment: @sawdust this interface is mipi csi-2  this interface has 5 lane ,each lane is 2 line because it is differential . 4 lane is for data lane other is for i2c for clock .So do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @sawdust, Highly likely. You messed up SPI with MIPI CSI-II interface.

Comment: @Mustafa, from your description it sounds like an external GPIO which controls XCE signal. I would check actual schematics to see how exactly the sensor connected to the SoC.